# Given $f(u,v)$ diffrenatiable twice and continous, and $g(x,y) = f(2x,xy)$

Tags: calculus

Given $f(u,v)$ diffrenatiable twice and continous, and $g(x,y) = f(2x,xy)$.

Find what is $g''_{xy}(x,y)$ using $f'_u(u,v), f'_v(u,v), f'_{vv}(u,v), f'_{uv}(u,v), f'_{uu}(u,v)$

Here's half of the solution, I understood everything except the last equation, can someone explain me how they calculated $g''_{xy}(x,y)$ please? (It's not the whole solution, but the other half is trivial)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g_x = f_u u_x + f_v v_x$

Now,

$$g_{xy} = (f_u)_y u_x + f_u u_{xy} + (f_v)_y v_x + f_v v_{xy}$$

For example let $h= f_u$. We have:

$$(f_u)_y = \frac{\partial }{\partial y} \left[ \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(u,v)\right] = \frac{\partial }{\partial y}  \left[ h(u,v) \right] = \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial h}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \frac{\partial h}{\partial v} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u^2} +\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial v\partial u} = u_y f_{uu} + v_y f_{uv}$$

Comment: $$g_{xy} = (f_u)_y u_x + f_u u_{xy} + (f_v)_y v_x + f_v v_{xy}$$ How did you get the second and the forth objects in the RHS? ($ f_u u_{xy}, f_v v_{xy}$)

Comment: and how would the answer change for $g''_{xx}$?

Comment: I figured it out myself. Thx Ahmed

Comment: I'm glad I helped